# Display one value and return another in text field with autocomplete Oracel Apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to be able to have a text field with autocomplete in Apex 5 that displays a client name, city and state, but just returns that client's client_id from the table.

I'm currently using a popup LOV

Is something like this even possible? I've been digging around for hours for a way to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins out there that accomplish this, but I haven't personally used them.

Here's what I've done:

1. Add a hidden item
2. Create a dynamic action to parse the autocomplete item and set the hidden item equal to this value.
3. Create a validation to ensure that the hidden item's value meets your expectations.

Comment: I thought of that, but the issue is that I need to be able to display the client's name, city and state since we have clients that have 5+ facilities nationally and need to be able to narrow them down.

Comment: What's stopping you from concatenating the client's name, city, state, and Id? If this is acceptable then I see no reason why you could not use the hidden item approach.

Comment: With text fields with autocomplete it only allows one column, you can't use a 

'select item d, item2 r
from table'

Comment: You're correct in saying that it only allows one column, but there's nothing stoping you from doing something like this: select name || '(' || id || ')' || ' - ' || city || ' , ' || state as d from table

Comment: If you go this route.. you would need either a DA to set your hidden item or a computation to set it.. that's up to you. Basically you just need to grab the Id (use the substr function) from the autocomplete when they submit the page.